# find -exec mv with relative path

Tags: bash, zsh

#### I have:

```
~/par1/
~/par2/*/*
```

#### Desired outcome:

`~/par2/*/*.gz` -> `~/par1/pmc_{}.gz`

e.g. `~/par2/par3/name.gz` -> `~/par1/pmc_name.gz`

e.g. flatten the files in `~/par2/` to `~/par1/` w/ some preprending to the filename

NOTE: this is for millions of files so it has to be `find`

#### Tried:

```
cd par2/
find . -name '*.gz' -maxdepth 2 -exec mv {} ../par1/pmc_{} \;
```

#### Got:

```
mv: rename ./par2/par3/file.gz to ../par1/pmc_./par2/par3/file.gz: No such file or directory
```

#### Problem:

`{}` is a filepath, not filename.

#### Thoughts:

Somehow make my 2nd `mv` arg use `basename`?

`mv -t` looks promising, but I'm on zsh.

Comment: Would using `-execdir` instead of `-exec` solve it? BTW, I strongly recommend making sure you have a good backup first, in case something goes horribly wrong, and also using `mv -i` or `mv -n` to avoid overwriting files if there's a naming conflict.

Comment: I fail to see the utility of `execdir` in this case. From its man: "Like `-exec`, but the specified command is run from the subdirectory containing the matched file, which is not normally the directory in which you started `find`."

Comment: Since `-execdir` runs the command in the subdirectory, it replaces `{}` with the filename instead of the filepath. Try with `-execdir echo {} \;` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), just use [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv):

```sh
% autoload -Uz zmv  # Add this to your .zshrc file, to not have to type it again.
% mkdir -p par1 par2/par3
% touch par2/par3/{0..9}.gz
% zmv -v 'par2/(*)/(*).gz' 'par1/pmc_$2.gz'  # -v for verbose
mv -- par2/par3/0.gz par1/pmc_0.gz
mv -- par2/par3/1.gz par1/pmc_1.gz
mv -- par2/par3/2.gz par1/pmc_2.gz
mv -- par2/par3/3.gz par1/pmc_3.gz
mv -- par2/par3/4.gz par1/pmc_4.gz
mv -- par2/par3/5.gz par1/pmc_5.gz
mv -- par2/par3/6.gz par1/pmc_6.gz
mv -- par2/par3/7.gz par1/pmc_7.gz
mv -- par2/par3/8.gz par1/pmc_8.gz
mv -- par2/par3/9.gz par1/pmc_9.gz
%
```

PS:

> `mv -t` looks promising, but I'm on zsh.

`mv` is not a [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) builtin. It's part of your OS.